# Implement a Carousel in Android app (no RenderScript)

Tags: android, carousel

I want to implement a carousel in my Android App. But I want it to work on "old" versions of Android (since 2.2). So I can't use RenderScript.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you!

Comment: what you did to run it in new version?

Comment: Have you succeeded if yes please tell me how???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used the ViewPager widget in the Google's Android Support Library (http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Hope it will help!